# UI Text Horizontal Overflow Wrap mode

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-ui

As shown in the image below, I have set the **text** to wrap and overflow in the box, but no matter what combinations I pick, when the sentence runs long, it continues to the right and disappears from the game view. What am I doing wrong that I cannot contain the text in the box and get it to enlarge if the user keeps talking?

[image]

Comment: You also have to set the `Pivot` to `X = 1` and than re-set `Pos X`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set horizontal overflow to **Wrap**, vertical to **Overflow**, and Size fitter's vertical fit to **Preferred size**. By modifying width of element, you decide which sentences are considered "long". Long sentences will be wrapped, and size fitter will change the height of the element.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have done the settings as you suggest, and the width of my text element keeps it in view, with my middle-right anchor, but when I run the app, anything longer than fitting in the element still spills over to the right and leaves the game view. I updated the image in my original question. Can you please see what I am doing wrong now? Many thanks

Comment: By setting horizontal fit to **Preferred size**, you let the content size fitter change the width of RectTransform (you see, now you can't change width by hand as its field is no longer interactable). Leave it **Unconstrained** instead. BTW, in my test project it didn't unlock when I set the right value back and even remove the fitter component, yet another bug in Unity. Removing the game object and creating a new one worked.